# Is it impossible to increment in a for loop by decimal numbers in actionScript 3 and get accurate results?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, floating-point

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere online, but this for loop, although seemingly valid, creates an infinite loop because actionscript does not seem to recognize 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and so on. This for loop will just trace 0, 0, 0, and so on infinitely.

Can anyone tell me why actionscript does this, and is there a way to get to precise decimal number increments in actionscript?

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<1; i = i + 0.1)
{
    trace(i);
}
```

Comment: You've defined `i` as an `int`. Try defining it as a `Number`.

Comment: As @HoboSapiens said, you can use `i` as a `Number` and then : `trace(i.toFixed(1));` to get `0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0`.

Comment: Why would you EVER want to do that?! It's absolutely wrong..

Comment: Yeah it's ridiculous, probably PO is not a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem, as reported in Hobo Sapiens's comment, is that you have declared `i` as `int`, but want it to store fractions. However, even after you have fixed that, you are likely to encounter rounding error issues. Adding up a floating point approximation to 0.1 is not a good way of getting the closest possible approximation to 0.9, or the exact value of 1.0.

There are generally two solutions:

1. Use a decimal data type. I have not been able to find a decimal arithmetic package for Actionscript, but that does not mean there isn't one.
2. Use an integer that represents a scaled version of the value you want. In the case of your loop, you would increment `i` by one on each iteration, and limit it to less than ten. You would then use a Number conversion of `i`, divided by ten, inside the loop. That results in using the closest floating point number to 0, 0.1, 0.2 etc. inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so I'll post it as an answer:

There are definitely cases where increments by a float value are useful. And if it was absolutely wrong, why would it then be possible at all?

What akmozo suggested is a good way to do it, instead of doing the increment `i = i + 0.1` you can do `i = Number((i+0.1).toFixed(decimalSpacesYouWant))`. This will return a number without the usual rounding problems. It gets especially useful with very small values (converging towards zero) which tend to flip into `Infinity` or `NaN` at some point.